# How to enable wss in websockets in dotnetcore 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, https, websocket, .net-core

I am new to DotNet. I am developing an application and it is done in dot net core 2.0 and uses WebSockets. I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-2.0) to get my WebSockets and it is working (using ws://).

I want to secure it with wss. I have created a self-signed certificate and modified my URL to use https and my REST request with https:// is working [In a different application]. When I followed the same and modified the URL to https and try to access my WebSocket using wss:// it is not working (connection is not enabled).

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are missing the port , dotnet core https is working on different port than http use this method in your client js file to get the correct url only replace /ws segment with your your own path

```
    static GetBaseUrl(type) {

const wsScheme = document.location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";

const webScheme = document.location.protocol === "https:" ? "https" : "http";

const port = document.location.port ? (":" + document.location.port) : "";

switch (type) {

case Enums.UrlType.Web:

return webScheme + "://" + document.location.hostname + port;

case Enums.UrlType.WebSocket:

//wss is causing issue on the production 

return wsScheme + "://" + document.location.hostname + port + "/ws/";

}

}
```